# Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<int, 3>'

Tags: c++, arrays, include, stdarray

I copy and pasted this exact code, found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) into my IDE, and got an error, I don't understand why it's happening and would like to learn why.

```
std::array<int, 3> a2 = {1, 2, 3}; // except after =
```

Comment: Is this being compiled with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yup, it is, made sure of it

Comment: Which compiler (and version) is it? And I haven't seen anything weird for `std::array`, but I have for others, so did you `#include <array>`?

Comment: Thanks, it was a silly mistake, I assumed it was included already like std::vector

Answer (score 51):

Make sure to remember `#include <array>`

> But if you don't include *any* standard headers, you should get a
> simpler error about `std` being undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If `#include <array>` does not work, as it did not for me, then use `#include <vector>`. I am a novice and cannot explain why this is, so my apologies if you are confused.

Comment: your vector implementation might include array on its own, but that must not be relied upon. Use `#include <array>` instead and pass appropriate compile options (like `-std=c++11`) if you're using an ancient compiler

Comment: Make sure that you're using a C++ 11 compiler